# Update on #temp table is faster then the @ table variable

Tags: sql-server

In the similar query Update on #temp table is faster then the @ table variable.

But I m forced to use table variable as I am wokring with function. I feel index is not being picked up for table variable. I have unique clustered index.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175010.aspx)

There is no way to explicitely generate indexes on table variables and no statistics are kept for any indexes generated by contstraints.

Comment: My update query  on table variable takes 56 sec  same query with temp table takes 13 sec. Thats a huge performance difference.

I can't pass temp table everytime to this function as that function is being called from different places.

Is there any workaround for this problem ?